# Java reflection gets superclass got unexpected result

Tags: java, reflection

While learning java reflection, I got some problem when testing `getSuperclass()`

Below is my test code:

```
System.out.println(java.io.Closeable.class.getSuperclass());
```

In my expectation, this line shall print something like `AutoClosable` because this is the class which `Closable` extends from. However this turns out to be `null`. I tried to explain this as Closable locates in `java.io` while AutoClosable locates in `java.lang` and `getSuperclass()` would only search in the package scope.

But this explanation does not make sense if I write like this:

```
Closeable closeable = () -> {

    };
System.out.println(closeable.getClass().getSuperclass());
```

The code above results in `class java.lang.Object`. The result makes this problem more peculiar and hard to understand.

How does java implements this `getSuperclass()` method and why does not this method return the result which corresponds to its name?

Comment: `AutoCloseable` is not a class.

Comment: and the packages have no influence in *searching* (actually there is no searching) (and `AutoCloseable` no being a class doesn't matter, the method returns `null`, as specified, for interfaces, and `Closeable` is one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither `Closeable` nor `AutoCloseable` are classes, they are both interfaces.

`getSuperclass` only returns super-classes, not super-interfaces. If called on something that is not a class itself (such as an interface, or a primitive type), the method returns `null`.

You may want to call `getInterfaces` instead.

Comment: ```Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class. If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned. If this object represents an array class then the Class object representing the Object class is returned.```
The full doc says entity could be interface, and getSuperclass() returns superclass of it. Since Closable extends AutoClosable, I do not see any conflicts between my code and this documentation.

Comment: I think the problem is that this method only returns ```Class<? super T>```. And interface will only extend from some other interfaces, so I think this method is meaningless for interfaces. Am I right?

Comment: @Yifeng isn''t the doc, you posted yourself, clear? "If this Class represents either the Object class, an **interface**, a primitive type, or void, then **null is returned**."

Comment: @carlos-heuberger Yeah I got it.  I just think interface shall not be included in the **entity** scope as written in doc. That paragraph was copied from oracle.

Comment: @Yifeng then all the reflection model must be changed, since "Instances of the class `Class` represent classes **and interfaces**" (probably also affecting the virtual machine implementations)

Answer (score 3):

`Closeable` is an interface, it has no superclass, only superinterfaces.

As it says [in the documentation of `getSuperclass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--):

> If this Class represents either the Object class, an interface, a primitive type, or void, then null is returned.

```
Closeable closeable = () -> {

};
```

is effectively creating concrete class which implements `Closeable`: `Closeable` has a single abstract method, `close()`, which you are implementing with an empty body. This is effectively the same as writing:

```
Closeable closeable = new Closeable() {
  @Override public void close() {}
}
```

This class *does* have a superclass, because all classes except `Object` have a superclass. That superclass is `Object`, per [the spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.1):

> If the `Identifier` in `ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate` denotes an interface, `I`, then an anonymous direct subclass of `Object` that implements `I` is declared.

Comment: Yeah. I understand the ```Object``` part because I did not notice that I really created an instance from that lambda expression. But from the docs you pasted, I think the "Class" means the superclass this method returns, not the original class. The problem now I am thinking is that if this method ```getSuperclass``` is meaningless for interfaces? Because this method returns ```Class<? super T>``` And interface could only extend from other interfaces. Even though interface could invoke this method, it will only return ```null```.

Comment: "I think the "Class" means the superclass this method returns, not the original class" no, it means the class on which you're invoking the method.

Answer (score 2):

That method [getSuperClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) says:

> Returns the Class representing the superclass of the entity (class, interface, primitive type or void) represented by this Class.

In your case, the super **class** is Object. Because you are looking at a class instance.

Meaning: in your second example, you created a lambda, basically: an anonymous inner **class**.

To gather information about implemented (or extended) interfaces, use [getInterfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces--).